# How to prevent terminal from opening in Mac

Tags: macos, user-interface, rust, terminal, window

I an running Rust on Mac and I have created a small example gui application using Fltk library. It is otherwise running perfectly.

When I click on binary file from file manager (Finder) in Mac, it opens a terminal window and then the application gui starts. Is there any way that I can prevent this terminal window from opening?

I checked the internet and found [one way](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/running-rust-app-without-showing-the-terminal/41859) for doing this on Windows. It is by adding following code:

```
#![windows_subsystem = "windows"]
```

However, this does not work on Mac. Is there any other solution?